# Grafana - How to Avoid Duplicate Dashboards When Using Different Variable Values

Tags: grafana, grafana-variable

I have several Grafana dashboards whose configuration should all be the same. The panels, graphs, titles of graphs, etc, should all be the same. The only difference between the dashboards is the values of the variables. I know I can set default values for the variables. But, what we have is a set of several conceptually similar dashboards that are suffering configuration drift. I'd like to conceptually have a single dashboard, but have 5 dashboards appear in Grafana (think: 5 virtual dashboards based off a single dashboard). This way, when I edit one dashboard (say, add a panel), the others also get the same feature upgrade. This is useful for a use case where we have 5 different environments/regions, each running their own version of a service. Each of the virtual dashboards would have the variables set to different values.

What I have: 5 different instances of a dashboard which in principle is the same. But since they are different dashboards in Grafana, they are suffering configuration drift.

What I want: 1 logical dashboard with 5 different links to jump into the dashboard, each link having its own set of variable values to apply.

What I've tried: [Dashboard Links](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/dashboards/build-dashboards/manage-dashboard-links/#manage-dashboard-links) do work. (The approach is to have a Dashboard Link for each environment / region, and the dashboard merely points to itself, but each link has different variable values set). However, this is difficult to maintain because I'm just given a URL text field to save all the variables in for that env. Maintaining the variable values for each env is therefore less than ideal, esp when the dashboard has 7 variables. (Also, the var values don't work properly unless I check "open link in new tab"). But, it does come pretty close to what I'd like. It feels like there might be a better, more appropriate, solution.

[image: Dashboard Link - less than ideal solution]

I'm using Grafana v9.5.5 (284c43c23d)

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a single dashboard and extended lust of values for your variables. Have you considered  that approach?

Comment: @markalex - I'm not sure I understand the idea, can you elaborate?

Comment: If you want to avoid drift between dashboards, and idea is to keep them the same, why not to use same dashboard, for all possible variables?

Comment: @markalex, yes, I would like to use the same dashboard, but then managing the vars becomes the problem. My "dashboard links" approach manages to use the same dashboard, but then I have to manage the variables in a text field (see image in the question). For dashboard A (aka use case A), I need var x's value to be 1, and var y's value to be 2. But for dashboard B (aka use case B), I need var x's value to be 3 and var y's value to be 4. So, the variables are already configured in the dashboard to apply to all use cases, I just need a way to manage the var _values_ for each of the 5 use cases.